# Cooking unit measure conversion library

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, data-conversion

I'm building an App of Cocktail recipes in React and users should be able to view dosage units in various measurements.

By default I'm showing all values in "ml" and users can choose to also view it in: "cl", "oz" or "part". Based on what users select, I would need to convert the quantity value based on the unit measure chosen.

My current code:

```
dosageData = [
  {
    "dosageIngredient": "gin",
    "quantity": "30",
    "unit": "ml",
  },
  {
    "dosageIngredient": "campari",
    "quantity": "30",
    "unit": "ml",
  },
  {
    "dosageIngredient": "sweet red vermouth",
    "quantity": "30",
    "unit": "ml",
  },
]
```

when the user change unit measure unitHandler() gets called passing the option chosen as either 'cl', 'ml', 'oz', 'part'

```
const unitHandler = (option) => {    
    const newDosage = dosageData;
    switch (option) {
      case "cl":
        newDosage.map((item) => {
          item.unit = option; //changing the unit value of each item in the array to "cl"     
          var amount = parseInt(item.quantity);     
          // amount = [conversion formula]
          setDosageData(newDosage); 
          setToggleUnit(option);
        });
        break;
      case "ml":
        newDosage.map((item) => {
          item.unit = option;
          setDosageData(newDosage);
          setToggleUnit(option);
        });        
        break;
      case "oz":
        ...
        break;
      case "part":
        ...
        break;
      default:
        Alert.alert("Value not found");
    }    
  };
```

if we use the "cl" option as an example I've managed to change the unit type within the array and save the new array.
I'm missing the step to convert the actual value "quantity" within the array.

I have both parameters From (toggleUnit) and To ("option") for the formula if needed.

I tried to use the following library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs but it only works between "ml" and "cl".

Is there a more complete library or an existing JS function available.

Answer (score 0):

For conversion between units of measure, in a past project I cooked up the following class which defines an object containing properties of a floating point value and the associated units.  Eg, "5 oz" or "2 gal".  The class is instantiated by either...

- `let v0 = new ValueUnits( '1 gal' );`  // value and unit separated by at least one space.
- `let v1 = new ValueUnits( 1, 'gal' );`

The class also implements a `toUnits( units )` method which converts the object value to the `units` passed.  For example...

- `v0.toUnits( 'qt' );`

...will convert the `v0` value property to US quarts.  Note that the `toUnits( units )` method rounds to a precision of 10 digits, so the `ValueUnits.unitsMap` table which defines the conversion equivalents must also contain 10 or more significant digits.  Otherwise if performing multiple unit conversions on the same `ValueUnits` object, small errors will begin to be introduced.

The code sample that follows defines the `ValueUnits` class, and then instantiates '1 gal', converting gal -> oz -> ml -> l -> qt -> gal...

```js
class ValueUnits {
  constructor( value, units ) {
    
    let fValue, fUnits;

        if ( units ) {
            fValue = value;
            fUnits = units;
        } else {
      [ fValue, fUnits ] = value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim().split( ' ' );
      fValue = parseFloat( fValue );
        }
    
    fUnits = fUnits || '';
    
        if ( ValueUnits.unitsMap[ fUnits ] ) {
            this.value = fValue;
            this.units = fUnits;
        } else {
            this.value = fValue;
            this.units = '';
        }
    
  }
  
  toUnits( units ) {

        if ( ValueUnits.unitsMap[ this.units ].dimension !== ValueUnits.unitsMap[ units ].dimension ) {
            this.value = NaN;
            this.units = null;
        } else {
            this.value = parseFloat( ( this.value * ValueUnits.unitsMap[ this.units ].conversion / ValueUnits.unitsMap[ units ].conversion ).toPrecision( 10 ) );
            this.units = units;
        }
        return this;
    
    }
    
    unitsDimension() {

        return ValueUnits.unitsMap[ this.units ].dimension;
        
    }
  
}

ValueUnits.unitsMap = {
  '':    { dimension: 'number', conversion: 1},
  '%':   { dimension: 'number', conversion: 1 / 100},

  'pts': { dimension: 'length', conversion: 1 },
  'px':  { dimension: 'length', conversion: 72 / 128 },
  'in':  { dimension: 'length', conversion: 72 },
  '"':   { dimension: 'length', conversion: 72 },
  'ft':  { dimension: 'length', conversion: 72 * 12 },
  "'":   { dimension: 'length', conversion: 72 * 12 },
  'cm':  { dimension: 'length', conversion: 72 / 2.54 },
  'mm':  { dimension: 'length', conversion: 72 / 25.4 },
  
  '/pts':{ dimension: '/length', conversion: 1 / 1 },
  '/in': { dimension: '/length', conversion: 1 / 72 },
  '/px': { dimension: '/length', conversion: 128 / 72 },

  'l':   { dimension: 'volume', conversion: 1 },      // liters is base
  'dl':  { dimension: 'volume', conversion: 1 / 10 },
  'cl':  { dimension: 'volume', conversion: 1 / 100 },            
  'ml':  { dimension: 'volume', conversion: 1 / 1000 },
  'oz':  { dimension: 'volume', conversion: 1 / 33.814022702 },  // us fluid ounce
  'gal': { dimension: 'volume', conversion: 1 / 0.2641720524 },  // us gallon
  'qt':  { dimension: 'volume', conversion: 1 / 1.0566882094 },  // us quart
  'pt':  { dimension: 'volume', conversion: 1 / 2.1133764189 }   // us pint
};


let x = new ValueUnits( '1 gal' );
console.log( x );

x.toUnits( 'oz' );
console.log( x );

x.toUnits( 'ml' );
console.log( x );

x.toUnits( 'l' );
console.log( x );

x.toUnits( 'qt' );
console.log( x );

x.toUnits( 'gal' );
console.log( x );
```

I realize that this class might not fit exactly how your code is currently constructed, but it abstracts the handling of quantities regardless of units, and ease the conversion to the desired units.

Note that 'parts' is not a unit, but rather a relative measure between substances.  That is, one can't definitively say that a `part` is one `gal`, but one can definitively say that `1 qt` is `0.25 gal`...

Also, the volume equivalents were sourced from https://www.unitconverters.net/volume/liters-to-gallons.htm.

Comment: Thanks @jon-trent for the answer. Since I have just a few options I've found the conversion ratio between them and applying it within a Switch Case statement. Not very elegant but practical I guess. I also figured out how to address the Part conversion. Thanks again!